# Añadir varios idiomas para una página en HTML y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una página (no todo el sitio web) que quiero que sea multi-idioma según una variable recibida en PHP. Mi idea es hacer documentos php con un array para todos los textos en todos los idiomas, y luego llamar solo al archivo del idioma correspondiente.

Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo, más simple. No soy experto en PHP y no se si esto va a hacer más lento el servidor si se hace desde este método. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En PHP con gettext y traduciendo en archivos .po con poedit, te dejo un enlace http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/lecciones/php-gettext.html

Comment: Sugeriría que lo hagas desde una base de datos. Guardarías el contenido bajo un `id`, una fila por cada idioma y según el idioma, traes el contenido en ese idioma. Funcionaría muy rápido. Por ejemplo Wordpress guarda el contenido de las páginas del sitio en tablas en una base de datos... En mi web tengo miles de páginas así, las llamo de la BD con un shortcode muy simple. En tu caso por ejemplo, algo así: `[content="7|1"]` para presentar el contenido con id `7` en la tabla en el idioma `1`, suponiendo que tienes tu propia convención numérica para idiomas, o `[content="7|es"]`  o algo así.